# What happened to “allow application to interact with desktop” checkbox in cluster manager for server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, cluster, failover, failovercluster

The cluster managing software for managing clusters on a windows server 2005 cluster had a checkbox for "allow application to interact with desktop" when creating a generic application resource. This appears to be gone in the management software for server 2008 clusters. Does anyone know where this option, if it still exists, is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option was removed in Server 2008 as a security enhancement. This is because the application runs as the cluster service account which has elevated privileges.

Even in 2003 clusters, the security best practice was to not have this checked.

Comment: Ok, so how does one go about managing permissions on private message queues on a clustered server?